# Merging teradata repeating rows to one

Tags: concatenation, rows, teradata

I am trying to use xmlagg to turn rows into a coma separated list. What I am having trouble with is the repeating values in col2. I need a new row for every repeating value in col2.

This is the source data:

```
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
|      Col1       |        Col2     |      Col3  |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
| VSPARK 27002026 | account_id      | account_id |
| VSPARK 27002026 | account_name    | Kontod 6-7 |
| VSPARK 27002026 | account_name    | Kontod 1-3 |
| VSPARK 27002026 | account_name    | Kontod 4-6 |
| VSPARK 27002026 | cash_type       | CASH_TYP   |
| VSPARK 27002026 | Currency        | CURRENCY   |
| VSPARK 27002026 | cust_type       | CUST_TYP   |
| VSPARK 27002026 | Residency       | RESIDENCY  |
| VSPARK 27002026 | transaction_amt | AMT        |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
```

This is the expected output:

```
+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      Col1       |                                         Col2                                         |                                 Col3                                  |
+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| VSPARK 27002026 | account_name, account_id, cash_type, cust_type, Residency, transaction_amt, Currency |  Kontod 6-7, account_id, CASH_TYP, CUST_TYP, RESIDENCY, AMT, CURRENCY |
| VSPARK 27002026 | account_name, account_id, cash_type, cust_type, Residency, transaction_amt, Currency |  Kontod 1-3, account_id, CASH_TYP, CUST_TYP, RESIDENCY, AMT, CURRENCY |
| VSPARK 27002026 | account_name, account_id, cash_type, cust_type, Residency, transaction_amt, Currency |  Kontod 4-6, account_id, CASH_TYP, CUST_TYP, RESIDENCY, AMT, CURRENCY |
+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Every repeating value in col2 should create an additional row in the end result. Unfortunately I have no idea how to accomplish this.

Any help is welcome!

**EDIT1:**

This is my current SQL:

```
SELECT report_name,
   TRIM(TRAILING ','
        FROM (XMLAGG(TRIM(insert_into_fields)|| ','
                     ORDER BY report_name) (VARCHAR(10000)))),
   TRIM(TRAILING ','
        FROM (XMLAGG(TRIM(select_from_fields)|| ','
                     ORDER BY report_name) (VARCHAR(10000))))
FROM
(SELECT report_name,
        field_name insert_into_fields,
        CASE
            WHEN account_mapping_formula_id IS NOT NULL THEN mapping_name
            WHEN formula IS NULL
                 AND account_mapping_Formula_id IS NULL THEN source_field_name
            ELSE formula
        END select_from_fields
 FROM mapping rf
 LEFT JOIN report r ON rf.report_id = r.report_id
 LEFT JOIN report_field e ON rf.target_column_id = e.field_id
 LEFT JOIN source_fields c ON rf.source_field_id = c.source_field_id
 LEFT JOIN account_mapping d ON rf.account_mapping_formula_id = d.account_mapping_id
 WHERE rf.report_id = 2) asd
GROUP BY report_name;
```

This is the current output:

```
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      Col1       |                                                      Col2                                                       |                                             Col3                                              |
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| VSPARK 27002026 | account_name, account_name, account_name, account_id, cash_type,cust_type, Residency, transaction_amt, Currency |  Kontod 6-7, Kontod 1-3, Kontod 4-6, account_id, CASH_TYP, CUST_TYP, RESIDENCY, AMT, CURRENCY |
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you show yor current SQL?

Comment: Sure, I will edit the original post With the SQL I am using. I will also post the currect output that I get with it.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch, that's not a user friendly data model :)

You need to duplicate the other rows for each account_name. One solution is to join to a distinct list of `(Col1,Col3)` and then add `Col3` to the final `GROUP BY`, something like this

```
WITH cte AS 
 (
   SELECT * 
   FROM asd -- this is your current Derived Table
 )
SELECT t2.report_name,
   'account_name' || ','||
   Trim(Trailing ','
        FROM (XmlAgg(Trim(t1.insert_into_fields)|| ','
                     -- Either sort by a unique column or no sort at all
                     ORDER BY t1.insert_into_fields) (VARCHAR(10000)))),
   t2.select_from_fields || ','||
   Trim(Trailing ','
        FROM (XmlAgg(Trim(t1.col3)|| ','
                     -- Either sort by a unique column or no sort at all
                     ORDER BY t1.insert_into_fields) (VARCHAR(10000))))
FROM cte AS t1
JOIN 
 ( -- list of report/account combinations
   SELECT DISTINCT report_name, select_from_fields
   FROM cte 
   WHERE insert_into_fields = 'account_name'
 ) AS t2
ON t1.report_name = t2.report_name
WHERE t1.insert_into_fields <> 'account_name'
GROUP BY t2.report_name, t2.select_from_fields
```